# React Native navigation package Error React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Showing error while opening app.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

This is a basic code I have created. See the steps to reproduce:

1. Created native project using command `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject`
2. Installed `npm install --save react-navigation`
3. Pasted the below code to App.js from react navigation documentation

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import {
   AppRegistry,
   Text,
   } from 'react-native';
   import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

   class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
       static navigationOptions = {
           title: 'Welcome',
       };
       render() {
           return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
       }
   }

   const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
       Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
   });

   AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
   ```
4. Run the app using `npm start` and opened in expo app android

Please note that none of the other files are edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expo and the standard React Native project templates have a slightly different way of declaring the app root component.

Whereas in standard React Native project, you use AppRegistry in `index.android.js`:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

In Expo, the framework registers the component for you, and all you need to do is export the component from your `Main.js`:

```
export default SimpleApp;
```

Here is an example of your code modified and pasted to Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.io/S1CZnFadZ